# why am i getting an error that is running for others in rust reqwest?

Tags: web-scraping, rust, rust-tokio, unwrap, reqwest

I an trying to build a webscraper via rust using reqwest library.
reqwest = "0.11.10"
scraper = "0.12.0"

I saw the example here: https://kadekillary.work/post/webscraping-rust/
I tried to do the same thing, but i am getting an error.

My code:
`

```
    extern crate reqwest;
    extern crate scraper;

use scraper::{Html,Selector};

fn main() {
    println!("WELCOME!");
    scrape_the_news("https://www.examplewebsite.com");
}

fn scrape_the_news(url: &str) {
    let mut urlsource = reqwest::get(url).unwrap();
    assert!(resp.status().is_success());

}
```

`

I am getting an error, the error is:
no method named `unwrap` found for opaque type `impl Future<Output = Result<Response, reqwest::Error>>` in the current scope

Thank you

Comment: i am sorry for all the error in the question. i am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Try `reqwest::blocking::get` instead of `reqwest::get`

Comment: @jmb thanks, it worked. But, i don't know why it worked for others but not me.

Comment: The example is probably using the old version of `reqwest`, before the async API was available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you use is outdated.

- `reqwest::get` is now an async function : it return immediately a "future" of the result without blocking. If you want to get the actual result, you have to wait for it to be available using `.await` on the future.
- with the edition 2018 or later, you don't need to use `extern crate` declarations anymore

I suggest you to get the examples from the official project : https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/master/examples/simple.rs